How can I get the executable folder of a tauri blazor app
I am writing a tauri Blazor app based on ASP.NET Core 8.
I'm trying to get the folder where my tauri Blazor exe runs.
I tried checking a folder using:
@code {
   private string patchFolder = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "sys");
}

When I try to print the patchFolder string, I only get the folder name /sys.
Is there any way for me to get the exe path in tauri Blazor in ASP.NET Core 8?

could you try to use the JavaScript code to get the Tauri application path

Is there no other way to do this?

so are you using blazor server or web assembly app? and also i would like to know how you are running the app from the release folder or from the dev command?

@JalpaPanchal I'm using Blazor Server with WebView2
I'm running the app in dev mode

I have tried this code and which result the current project directory. my tauri app is also placed in the blazor project.
ShowPath.razor:
@page "/showpath"
@inject ILogger<ShowPath> Logger

<h3>Executable Path</h3>
<p>@patchFolder</p>

@code {
    private string patchFolder;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Get the directory of the running executable
        patchFolder = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "sys");

        // Log for debugging
        Logger.LogInformation("Patch Folder Path: {path}", patchFolder);
    }
}




One question, are you using the Tauri V2? Why did I test the same code you wrote and it returns the path empty, it only returns what I pass as in the /sys

@Kobe yes i am using Tauri V2. could you share if you have any reproducible steps. as i have just created .net blazor server project with .net 7 and used this above code which result me full path

I did some tests on Visual Studio's default Blazor When I create a blazor web app I get the path correctly However, when I create a Blazor webassembly this problem occurs.
image web app https://imgur.com/IMfiZ3K
image webassembly https://imgur.com/KfVM3La

@Kobe faced the same issue with the web assembly because it does not have direct access to the file system. i am trying to use the javascript still not able to get path with it will share the result soon

Question about your tauri app that you tested, is it using a web app? If yes, how can I do this

i am using blazor server app not blazor web assembly app @Kobe

@Kobe image

@Kobe i am little confuse about your question as you sherd picture and mentioned in comment that you are getting expected result by using blazor server app so may i know what you are looking for

I want to use tauri with blazor, just like there is maui blazor, a local app where you can use C# code with Html and css
The test I did was to see if the issue of not showing the directory was from Blazor or Tauri, and I did a test in Visual Studio's default Blazor, but I want to build my app using Tauri with Blazor

@Kobe correct me if i misunderstood. so for a now you are running the app from the visual studio. and now you would like to access the blazor from the tauri. to do that you set code like this in the tauri.conf.json :  "productName": "Tauri App",  "version": "0.1.0",  "identifier": "com.tauri.dev",  "build": {    "frontendDist": "../wwwroot",    "devUrl": "http://localhost:5016",    "beforeDevCommand": "dotnet run",    "beforeBuildCommand": "dotnet build"  } and run command npx tauri dev from the command prompt to run the tauri app with blazor

I created it in visual studio just to find out the source of the path problem.
I want to keep my tauri app, but I wanted a way to change the blazor that comes with tauri from webassembly to web app

@Kobe sorry i did not got your point

To be clearer, I wanted a way to be able to use blazor code in my tauri app without using an external server or a webassembly. The same exists in Maui, for example
